# UIViewController back button not shown

Tags: ios, swift

rootViewController -> tabviewcontroller -> viewController1 -> viewController2

In such order, back button works fine but when viewController2 pops back to viewController1, viewController1's backbutton is not shown, so I cannot go back to tabviewcontroller.

What is the possible reason? Thanks for help.

Here is my storyboard

[image]

```
//after viewWillAppear
func initNavigation(){
    //topItem is self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem
    guard topItem != nil else {
        return
    }
    //custom letButtonBar just make tabviewcontroller title at left
    //other viewcontroller title is "" so position still at center
    let leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(title:  "", style:UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: nil)
    let attr = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.white, NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "iconfont", size: UIFont.buttonFontSize)!]

    leftButton.setTitleTextAttributes(attr, for: .normal)
    leftButton.setTitleTextAttributes(attr, for: .highlighted)
    leftButton.setTitleTextAttributes(attr, for: .disabled)
    leftButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
    leftButton.isEnabled = false

    topItem?.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.white
    topItem?.setLeftBarButton(leftButton, animated: true)
    topItem?.title = ""

}
//tabviewcontroller:
override func initNavigation() {
    super.initNavigation()
    topItem?.leftBarButtonItem?.title = "tabviewcontrollerTitleAtLeft"
}
//viewcontroller1
 override func initNavigation() {
    super.initNavigation()
    self.navigationItem.title = "viewController1TitleAtCenter"
}
//viewcontroller2
 override func initNavigation() {
    super.initNavigation()
    self.navigationItem.title = "viewController2TitleAtCenter"
}
```

I tried many times, found a solution, I delete super.initNavigation() in viewcontroller1, it works fine finally, still do not know the reason.

Comment: I think you call initNavigation in some wrong place in ViewController1. Also why do you not use backItem to change back button title?

Comment: I delete super.initNavigation() in viewcontroller1, it works fine finally, still do not know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

It seems maybe you can have another `UINavigationController` between VCs like the following:

[image]

Hide the navigation bar of the first one. and use the second navigation bar as the root.

Comment: Not this reason. I check my code, only one UINavigationController, one RootViewController

Comment: As I remember, you can't put one UINavigationController into other navigation controller. It will produce a crash in runtime.

Comment: its not crash in this case. The second nav is a child of tab.

Answer (score 0):

You should check how you are presenting and popping VCs. There is a possibility that it's caused by something relating to that.